# Sending Multiple Data to Views Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to use ckeditor plugin, and pagination in my application; but there is a problem.

If I load data of pagination ckeditor doesn't work. If I load data of ckeditor pagination doesn't work.

`$data['pagination']=$this->pagination->create_links();`      `$data['ckeditor']=$this->data;`

```
$this->load->view('index', $data); // pagination
```

In `index.php` I can write `echo $pagination`, but ı cant use `$ckeditor` because its usage is the following:

`<?php echo display_ckeditor($ckeditor); ?>`

[This is ckeditor controller](http://nukium.com/developpement-php/codeigniter/ckeditor-helper-for-codeigniter/)

Comment: do you have any errors? did you try var_dump for variables? Also, why do you load view index two times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at least ı solved problem. but you cant send multiple data to view as ı did.

you need to do this:

```
    $this->data['page_links']=$this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$this->data);
```

ı made ckeditor in construct so ı can use it everywhere.

```
    $this->data['ckeditor'] = array(

        //ID of the textarea that will be replaced
        'id'    =>  'content',
        'path'  =>  'js/ckeditor',

        //Optionnal values
        'config' => array(
            'toolbar'   =>  "Full",     //Using the Full toolbar
            'width'     =>  "750px",    //Setting a custom width
            'height'    =>  '100px',    //Setting a custom height

        ),

        //Replacing styles from the "Styles tool"
        'styles' => array(

            //Creating a new style named "style 1"
            'style 1' => array (
                'name'      =>  'Blue Title',
                'element'   =>  'h2',
                'styles' => array(
                    'color'             =>  'Blue',
                    'font-weight'       =>  'bold'
                )
            ),

            //Creating a new style named "style 2"
            'style 2' => array (
                'name'      =>  'Red Title',
                'element'   =>  'h2',
                'styles' => array(
                    'color'             =>  'Red',
                    'font-weight'       =>  'bold',
                    'text-decoration'   =>  'underline'
                )
            )               
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send an array of them to the view

```
$arrToView['ckeditor'] = $ckEditorData;
$arrToView['pagination'] = $paginationData;   
$this->load->view('index', $arrToView);
```

I Hope thats what you are trying to do

Comment: ı tried it but it returns array  echo $pagination; // it works, no problem  echo $keditor; // writing "array" on the page.

ckeditor usage in view is this:  <?php echo display_ckeditor($ckeditor); ?>

Comment: if the $pagination is an array then loop through it 
foreach($pagination as $page)
echo $page;

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
$this->load->view('index', array(
    'pagination'    =>   $this->pagination->create_links(),
    'ckeditor'    =>  $this->data
));
```

View

```
display_ckeditor(array($ckeditor));
```

Edit: 
Im still confused.
make sure you have setup your pagination correctly, $this->pagination->create_links() is not a magic feature, you need to setup pagination on a Controller basis.  read the manual or view my example.

```
public function index($offset=0){

$limit = $this->config->item('tbl_rows_returned');

//find pages based on limits and offset
$pages = Page::find('all', 
            array('limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset, 'order' => 'created_at desc')
);
//count total pages
$count = Page::count();

//init pagination attributes
$config = array(
        'base_url' => site_url('admin/pages'),
        'total_rows' => $count,
        'per_page' => $limit,
        'uri_segment' => 3
    );
$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

//load the view and pagination data
$this->load->view('templates/admin', array(
        'content'  =>  'pages/admin/_index',
        'pagination'  =>  $this->pagination->create_links(),
        'pages'  =>  $pages
));
```

}

Comment: ckeditor data is empty.  The way I and `userB` posted are the correct way to pass data, just different methods.  this is your problem line `$data['ckeditor']=$this->data;`  $this->data must represent some value